# Why parsing my date succeeds when using request, but fails when using reqwests?

Tags: datetime, encoding, rust, runtime-error

I have a string containing the following date `2015-07-05T11:02:25+00:00`.

I use the following code to parse it (using chrono crate)

```
    let pub_date = str::replace(entry.pub_date().unwrap(), "-0000", "+0000");
    return DateTime::parse_from_rfc2822(&pub_date)
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| {
            panic!(
                "pub_date for item {:?} (value is {:?}) can't be parsed. {:?}",
                &entry, pub_date, e
            )
        })
        .naive_utc();
```

When I get that content using request crate, the date is correctly parsed.
But when I use the reqwests crate, it fails with the error message

```
[2019-09-07 10:48:45.472951 +02:00] INFO [rrss2imap::feed] src\feed.rs:152: There should be new entries, parsing HTML content
thread 'main' panicked at 'pub_date for item Item { title: Some("[Avis/BD] Capitaine Trèfle"), link: Some("https://fr.rec.arts.fantasy.narkive.com/Z2rKs6RJ/avis-bd-capitaine-trefle"), description: None, author: None, categories: [], comments: None, enclosure: None,
guid: None, pub_date: Some("2015-07-05T11:02:25+00:00"), source: None, content: None, extensions: {}, itunes_ext: None, dublin_core_ext: None } (value is "2015-07-05T11:02:25+00:00") can't be parsed. ParseError(Invalid)', src\feed.rs:236:17
```

If I debug (using VSCode Rust debugger), the error value simply contains `Invalid (3 '\x3')`. But I don't understand where it come from ... (I suppose it can be some kind of encoding issue, but it puzzles me, as the whole object seems totally correct).

And I don't understand what is going wrong. Has anybody any idea ?

Comment: Not a valid RFC2822 time, simple as that. The issue is that `+00:00` isn't a valid timezone descriptor for this format; `+0000` would be.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld you should set that as an answer, cause it was the correct answer ...

Comment: I wasn't sure if it would really be that simple. Wrote the answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the answer was a simple RFC2282 non-compliance: the source was sending `2015-07-05T11:02:25+00:00`. As the RFC states, timezone information is without the `:` in this format.

Comment: Please note that there is a crate ([rfc822_sanitizer](https://docs.rs/rfc822_sanitizer/)) that can auto-fix (at the obvious price of consumed cpu time) that can auto-fix rfc822 datetimes ... and it solved the bug !